# How to open link when add new group? laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two records.

[image: table1]

When I click on +. Must open the desired group. But I see it that way. That is, it opens both groups.

[image: table2]

slider_gorups table

```
Schema::create('slider_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();    
});
```

sliders table

```
Schema::create('sliders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('userId')->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('groupId')->nullable();
    $table->string('src')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

groups.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('admin::sliders.index',   $sliderGroup->id) }}" class="mr-1">
    <i class="la la-plus text-grey text-shadow-custom font-medium-4 font-weight-normal"></i>
</a>
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('slider-groups', 'Admin\SliderGroupController');
Route::prefix('slider-groups/{sliderGroupId}')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('sliders', 'Admin\SliderController');
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what your problem is. As far as I understand it, you want to click on the "+" sign (button/link?) and follow that link to another route (doesn't happen), right? In that case, we'd need to see your routes in your web.php and the implementation of the link/button in your blade view.

Comment: Your web.php doesn't contain a route with `->name('admin::sliders.index')`. I just see a route whose url will be `slider-groups/{sliderGroupId}/sliders`.

Answer (score -2):

put your groups code

i think problem is in their id attribute

each group must has its own id and same with its own "+" id!

in this case when you click on "+", it will open group with same id